# Why is there no predicate in "in vino veritas"?

Tags: verbs, predicate, esse

The latin aphorism, penned by Alcaeus of Mytilene,

***in vino veritas***

does not contain any predicate. I assume that *esse* is implied but I haven't come across any other aphorisms leaving out verbs.

Is it ok to leave out the verb *esse* if it is implied?

e.g. `Nocere facile, prodesse difficile` instead of `Nocere facile est, prodesse difficile`

Can you also leave out other verbs?

e.g. `Homo sum, nihil humani a me alienum` instead of `Homo sum, humani nihil a me alienum puto`

Comment: Alcaeus was a Greek poet and didn't know Latin. Wiki says the first word-for-word use of the phrase is by Erasmus.

Comment: @TKR Primary sources would certainly be interessting to read!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Pinkster 2015](http://www.oxfordscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199283613.001.0001/acprof-9780199283613) mentions the following observable trends regarding the omission of esse.

- it is more frequent with **the 3rd person** than in the 1st or 2nd;
- it is more frequent with **present indicative** forms;
- it is more frequent in **simple nominal sentences** etc. (see pp. 201-204 for more details).

> [Stolz and Schmalz](https://books.google.com/books?id=1RKPZSUBNaMC&lpg=PR15&dq=laut-und%20formenlehre%20syntax%20und%20stilistik&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false) add that the omission of esse is regular in proverb-like statements ("Sprichwörter und Sentenzen," see para 198:a).

[Rubio 2009](https://www.degruyter.com/view/books/9783110205626/9783110205626.195/9783110205626.195.xml) goes even further by saying that

> "**The absence of a copulative verb**, especially in proverbial expressions and in apodiptic statements, **is a common trend in Latin of all periods**, but in the Latin Bible this is simply the norm" (p. 218; empaphasis mine - Alex B.).

On the other hand, [Cabrillana](https://usc-es.academia.edu/Concepci%C3%B3nCabrillana) 2007 ([la Universidad de Santiago de Compostela](https://www.uam.es/proyectosinv/regula/ccabrillana_usc.html), Spain) argues that even though the ellipsis of esse and some other verbs (monstror, appareo, exsto etc.) is common in the contexts mentioned above, it is "not always the most frequent."

[In the same study](https://www.uam.es/proyectosinv/regula/2_1_griego.html), Cabrillana reports cases of **verbal ellipsis with verbs "having а full semantic content in concrete constructions."**

Answer (score 7):

Yes to the first, usually no to the second.

In Latin, *esse* can almost always be dropped if the meaning is clear. This is even true when it's connected to another verb form, like in a perfect passive *captus [est]* or a passive periphrastic *delenda [est]*.

Linguistically, this is called *zero copula*, and also appears in e.g. Russian. Consider also English headlines, such as "Event [is/was] disrupted by geese" or "Parliament [is] in session again". Looking through a list of Latin sayings, *esse* is omitted in several others: *amicus Plato [est], sed magis amica veritas [est]*; *ars longa [est], vita brevis [est]*, etc.

Other verbs generally can't be omitted in the same way; if no verb is apparent, I automatically assume a form of *esse*.

Comment: Can esse also be left out if it's used in the subjunctive? What about the temporal aspects; is the left out esse always in the present or could it be for example in its imperfect?

Comment: @stendarr it could be, as long as it's clear — which it usually isn't, since you mark the verb to change tense or mood, and you can't do that with the verb missing. Still I can imagine scenarios where it would probably work.